# Inline conditional statement returning an error

Tags: javascript

I have an issue/concern with something I am doing

```
($location.$$path === '/lines') ? $scope.displayLogout = true : $scope.displayLogout = false;
```

if I do it the way above, JSHint provides an error

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

but if I come up this way

```
if ($location.$$path === '/lines') {
   $scope.displayLogout = true;
}else {
   $scope.displayLogout = false;
}
```

everything works properly.

Isn't the same?

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is a bit wrong try

```
$scope.displayLogout = ($location.$$path === '/lines') ?  true : false;
```

or

```
$scope.displayLogout = ($location.$$path === '/lines');
```